# Python mechanize fails with a certain if condition, but succeeds with another... have no idea why

Tags: python, mechanize

This is a simple bot that logs into a vbulliten messageboard, scans a thread for certain text, and then posts this text in a newly formatted way.  In my while loop I have an if else conditional where x == 1 for testing purposes.  When I do this, mechanize works fine, it selects the correct form, and the code functions fine. But when I simply change the if else to be based on a certain time, I get a "formnotFound" error.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime
import mechanize
import re
import sqlite3
import time

def login(page):

    br = mechanize.Browser()
    br.set_handle_redirect(True)
    br.set_handle_referer(True)
    br.set_handle_equiv(True)
    br.set_handle_refresh(True)
    br.set_handle_robots(False)
    br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]

    br.open("http://www.nottherealsite.com")

    br.select_form(nr=0)
    br.form['vb_login_username']='notrealusername'
    br.form['vb_login_password']='notrealpassword'
    br.form['cookieuser'] = ['1']
    br.submit()
    br.open(page)

    return br


br = login("http://www.nottherealsite.com")
html = br.response().read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
x = 1

# Ahead you'll see two functions, insertData() and extraction().
# I didn't include them in my submission here 
# because I don't think it's necessary. they dont involve anything to do with 
# mechanize, they just strip data out of the pages. The functions also work fine
# with the x==1 conditional, fyi

while True:
    now = datetime.now()
    minute = now.minute
```

This works fine:

```
    if x == 1:

        print "it is working . . ."
        insertData()
        votes = extraction()
        br.select_form(nr=6)
        br.form['message'] = votes
        br.submit()

        x = 2

    else:

        print "we are now done"
        break
```

If I replace `x== 1` with `minute > 30`, I get a form not found error in mechanize (and yes, the time was past the 30 minute mark):

```
    if minute > 30:

            print "it is working . . ."
            insertData()
            votes = extraction()
            br.select_form(nr=6)
            br.form['message'] = votes
            br.submit()

            # remember, I am just concerned about mechanize going through
            x = 2

        else:

            print "we are now done"
            break
```

I know it might be hard to tell what practical thing I am doing with this, but remember, the above code is for testing purposes right now. Does anyone have any idea why mechanize would fail when I change the if else statement? It doesn't make any sense to me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used to ran into a similar problem with you in other language(C#) some days before. I don't know if my solution is applicable to you or not.

My solution is: wait until the web page is fully loaded. If your library (machanize) supplied a callback when the page is fully loaded, then use it. Or just wait for some seconds.